# How to create docker slave builds for non docker Jenkins master

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I just have a Jenkins master that installed on Linux box and its not a dockerized. But I just wanna create some slaves on docker that will taken care of build execution that is being running on Master Jenkins.

```
arrchana@instance-1:~$ uname -a
Linux gcp_instance-0 3.11.0-1029-gcp #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 22 13:06:42 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

docker Version:
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

I just pull the below image on docker:

**bibinwilson/jenkins-slave**

And enabled tcp port on docker.service and check the test connection on Master Jenkins and It returned response.

And added Image name as bibinwilson/jenkins-slave  and connection though ssh and added credentials to connect the docker.

And mapped the label into one of the Job config and triggered the job. But Its always in offline and the image is not spin.

Any help would be appreciated. Is there any image that can suite my requirement?

My project is **Java8+maven** based and docker is running on Ubuntu.

Docker Slave setting details on Jenkins:

[image]

For the above image I just entered valid tcp and Host credential and clicked TEST Connection which return response back.

**Docker Template settings:**

[image]

**Docker Slave setup**

[image]

I just saved the above changes and mapped "Docker" in job config and triggered the job but its still showing as offline.

Comment: can you share more about the slave settings. have you tried using [docker slave agents plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Slaves+Plugin)

Comment: Updated the question. Please check and let me know